# Logical operation between two Boolean lists

Tags: python, list, logical-operators

I get a weird result and I try to apply the `and` or the `or` operator to 2  Boolean lists in python. I actually get the exact opposite of what I was expecting.

```
[True, False, False] and [True, True, False]
> [True, True, False]

[True, False, False] or [True, True, False]
> [True, False, False]
```

Is that normal, and if yes, why?

Comment: Well, what were you expecting?

Comment: What I said "I actually get the exact opposite of what I was expecting". I was expecting that the first command would lead to the second result and the second command to lead to the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lists aren't comparing each individual value, they're comparing the existence of values in the list.

For any truthy variables `a` and `b`:

```
a and b
> b #The program evaluates a, a is truthy, it evaluates b, b is truthy, so it returns the last evaluated value, b.
a or b
> a #The program evaluates a, a is truthy, so the or statement is true, so it returns the last evaluated value, a.
```

Now, truthy depends on the type. For example, integers are truthy for `my_int != 0`, and are falsy for `my_int == 0`. So if you have:

```
a = 0
b = 1
a or b
> b #The program evaluates a, a is falsy, so the or statement goes on to evaluate b, b is truthy, so the or statement is true and it returns the last evaluated value b.
```

Answer (score 13):

If what you actually wanted was element-wise boolean operations between your two lists, consider using the `numpy` module:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([True, False, False])
>>> b = np.array([True, True, False])
>>> a & b
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a | b
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 8):

This is normal, because `and` and `or` actually evaluate to one of their operands. `x and y` is like

```
def and(x, y):
    if x:
        return y
    return x
```

while `x or y` is like

```
def or(x, y):
    if x:
        return x
    return y
```

Since both of your lists contain values, they are both ["truthy"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/6779307) so `and` evaluates to the second operand, and `or` evaluates to the first.

Comment: Your answer was the first correct one, thank. However I find the Davy one clearer, hence +1 but not question validation. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

I think you need something like this:

```
[x and y for x, y in zip([True, False, False], [True, True, False])]
```

Comment: I am not asking how to get it right. I am asking why I get this result...

Answer (score 3):

Both lists are truthy because they are non-empty.

Both `and` and `or` return the operand that decided the operation's value.

If the left side of `and` is truthy, then it must evaluate the right side, because it could be falsy, which would make the entire operation false (false `and` anything is false). Therefore, it returns the right side.

If the left side of `or` is truthy, it does not need to evaluate the right side, because it already knows that the expression is true (true `or` anything is true). So it returns the left side.

If you wish to perform pairwise comparisons of items in the list, use a list comprehension, e.g.:

```
[x or y for (x, y) in zip(a, b)]     # a and b are your lists
```

Answer (score 2):

Very convenient way:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.logical_and([True, False, False], [True, True, False])
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> np.logical_or([True, False, False], [True, True, False])
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 2):

Мore functional:

```
from operator import or_, and_
from itertools import starmap

a = [True, False, False]
b = [True, True, False]
starmap(or_, zip(a,b))  # [True, True, False]
starmap(and_, zip(a,b))  # [True, False, False]
```