# Trying to bitwise and two lists in python

Tags: python, command-line, data-science, python-3.7

I did the following in the python shell. The first and third output is correct but the second and is just wrong. I know i can use the zip function to do this but i want to know why python does this.

```
>>> [1,1,1,1] and [1,0,0,0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
>>> [1,0,0,0] and [1,1,0,0]
[1, 1, 0, 0]
>>> [1,1,1,1] and [0,0,0,0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Who said you can do bitwise `and` like that?  This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419342/logical-operation-between-two-boolean-lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python and / or operators return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477850/python-and-or-operators-return-value)

Comment: I think so @Georgy, plus a confusion between logical and bitwise operators.

Comment: See also [Python AND operator on two boolean lists - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192163/python-and-operator-on-two-boolean-lists-how) which directly addresses the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python AND operator on two boolean lists - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192163/python-and-operator-on-two-boolean-lists-how)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned at : [Python AND operator on two boolean lists - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192163/python-and-operator-on-two-boolean-lists-how)

"and simply returns either the first or the second operand, based on their truth value. If the first operand is considered false, it is returned, otherwise the other operand is returned." by **Martijn Pieters**

```
[1,1,1,1] and [1,0,0,0]
=> [1, 0, 0, 0] which is second operand while first is true.
```

Another example:

```
a=2
print(a==3 and [1,1,0,0])
```

return `False` while `a==3 is false`

And

```
a=2
print(a==2 and [1,1,0,0])
```

return `[1,1,0,0]` while `a==2 is true`